# Query to find the subtract of each column from the following column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Hi everyone hope you are doing well
   I have a table with this structure
   Table 1:

```
 [dbo].[ValueTest] (Date , PorojectCode , Value)
```

It has this data

```
('1397/04/01' , 'A' , 100) , ('1397/04/03' , 'A' , 120) , ('1397/04/05' ,'A',140)
```

I need to have the result below :

```
 ProjectCode    Value
-------------   -------
    A              20
    A              20

I Mean I need to have the subtract of the value of each column from the following column
I have tried this query but I did not get the result
```

Thanks for helping me

```
Select ProjectCode , 
       (Select v.Value - v2.Value
        From [dbo].[ValueTest] V2
        Where v2.DateKey >= V.DateKey)
from [dbo].[ValueTest] V
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LAG()` to subtract the value from the previous value, ordered by DateKey.

```
SELECT ProjectCode, (V.value - LAG(v.value) over (order by Datekey)) as val
from [dbo].[ValueTest] V;
```

But this will give you an extra `NULL` for the first value since we are doing `100 - NULL` (Non existing row since the row with val 100 is the first one).

One way around this is by removing the `NULL` with a `CTE`

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT ProjectCode, (V.value - LAG(v.value) over (order by Datekey)) as val
from [dbo].[ValueTest] V
)

SELECT * FROM CTE 
where val IS NOT NULL;
```

**Result**

```
ProjectCode val
A   20
A   20
```